# Databricks Notebook Command Status Handshake with ADF

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-databricks

I have an ADF pipeline which has around 30 activities that call Databricks Notebooks. The activities are arranged sequentially, that is, one gets executed only after the successful completion of the other.

However, at times, even when there is a run time error with a particular notebook, the activity that calls the notebook is not failing, and the next activity is triggered. Ideally, this should not happen.

So, I want to keep an additional check on the link condition between the activities. I plan to put a condition on the status of the commands running in the notebook (imagine a notebook has 10 python commands, I want to capture the status of 10th command).

Is there a way to configure this? Appreciate ideas. Thank you.

Comment: if there is an exception from execution of the command, then it should fail databrics job

Answer (score 0):

I did try at my end - When there was an exception in the code - I did see the output of the error in the activity output. But in my case the activity failed like @Alex mentioned.

[image]

In your case you could check the output of the activity and see whether there is any run error. If there is no runError, then proceed with the next activity.

```
@activity('Notebook2').output.runError
```